# Constraints over multiple columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[charges]
(
    [recordid] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [chargeNumber] [int] NULL,
    [name] [nvarchar](100) NULL,
    [date] [datetime] NULL,
    [hunID] [bigint] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_charges] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([recordid] ASC)
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[charges] WITH CHECK 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_charges_Column_Range] 
       CHECK (([chargeNumber] >= (1) AND [chargeNumber] <= (3)))
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[charges] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_charges_Column_Range]
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[charges] 
   ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_charges_date]  
       DEFAULT (getutcdate()) FOR [date]
GO
```

How can I ensure that no duplicate charge numbers are allowed, per `id`? In the examples below I have omitted unnecessary columns. I can't figure out a constraint that would do this. Should I be doing this in the application rather than at database level?

I would allow rows like this, where each ID has 1-3 in the `chargeNumber` column:

```
+----------+----+--------------+--------+
| recordid | id | chargeNumber | name   |
+----------+----+--------------+--------+
| 1        | 7  | 1            | Peter  |
| 2        | 7  | 2            | Roger  |
| 3        | 7  | 3            | Emily  |
| 4        | 8  | 1            | Rachel |
| 5        | 8  | 2            | Dave   |
| 6        | 8  | 3            | Bob    |
+----------+----+--------------+--------+
```

but not like this:

```
+----------+----+--------------+--------+
| recordid | id | chargeNumber | name   |
+----------+----+--------------+--------+
| 1        | 7  | 1            | Peter  |
| 2        | 7  | 2            | Roger  |
| 3        | 7  | 3            | Emily  |
| 4        | 7  | 1            | Rachel |
| 5        | 8  | 1            | Dave   |
| 6        | 8  | 1            | Bob    |
+----------+----+--------------+--------+
```

Note the duplicate `chargeNumbers` for id's `7` and `8`.  `recordid 4` and either 5/6, would not be allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put a UNIQUE CONSTRAINT on the id & chargeNumber columns together.

Comment: Would that work per row? I need the ability for the same ID to be entered 3 times.

Comment: Yes, it would enforce that you can't enter the same combination of id/chargeNumber more than once.  You could enter the same ID as many times as you wanted, as long as the same id wasn't combined with the same chargeNumber.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you need:

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IDX_charges_id_chargeNumber] ON [dbo].[charges]
(
    [id] ASC,
    [chargeNumber] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```